# Matlab, figures and for loops

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the following simple function; $y=A.*x$ with different A parameter values i.e. A=0,1,2,3 all on the same figure. I know how to plot simple functions i.e. $y=x$ by setting up x as a linspace vector so defining x=linspace(0,10,100); and I know that one can use the hold command.

I thought that one could simply use a for loop, but the problem then is getting a plot of all the permutations on one figure, i.e. I want a plot of y=t,2*t,3*t,4*t on the same figure. My attempt is as follows:

```
x=linspace(0,10,100);

%Simple example
Y=x;

figure;
plot(Y);

%Extension
B=3;

F=B*x;

figure;
plot(F);

%Attempt a for loop
for A= [0,1,2,3] 
G=A*x;

end

figure;
plot(G);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would plot your for loop example:

```
figure;
hold all;
for A=[0,1,2,3] 
    G=A*x;
    plot(G);
end
```

`figure` creates a new figure. `hold all` means that subsequent plots will appear on the same figure (`hold all` will use different colours for each plot as opposed to `hold on`). Then we plot each iteration of `G` within the loop.

You can also do it without the loop. As with most things in Matlab, removing the loop should give improved performance.

```
figure;
A=[0,1,2,3];
G=x'*A;
plot(G);
```

`G` is the outer product of the two vectors `x` and `A` (with `x` having been transposed into a column vector). `plot` is used to plot the columns of the 100x4 matrix `G`.

Comment: +1 for explaining difference between ``hold all`` and ``hold on``.